# Google App engine - need to use userService in each page

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, servlets, gmail, servlet-filters

On `Google app engine`, do I need to `import & initialize` the object `userService` to log-in the user through Gmail in each page (jsp), or is there a better way to achieve this? Using `filters` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sessions, when you login store the user id and get appropriate data to sessions that you will frequently use. Then only check sessions before the userService.

Comment: If you mean `Servlet` sessions, according to another post I have to add `<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>` to `web.xml`.